# I can't seem replicate my data in firestore to algolia

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, algolia

Basically, I'm trying to replicate my data that's already in firebase into algolia through firebase cloud functions. The code doesn't compile and I can't seem to figure out why.

I'm using typescript, not javascript and am following this article right here. 
https://medium.com/@soares.rfarias/how-to-set-up-firestore-and-algolia-319fcf2c0d37
I'm also working in VScode

// This is at the top of my file
    const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch')

```
const algoliaClient = 
algoliasearch(functions.config().algolia.appid, 
functions.config().algolia.apikey)

export const sendCollectionToAlgolia = 
functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => 
{
const collectionIndex = algoliaClient.initIndex('Organizations')
const db = admin.firestore()
const algoliaRecords = []

const querySnapshot = await db.collection("Organizations").get()

querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        const document = doc.data()



        const record = {
            objectID: doc.id,
            "orgUsername": document.orgUsername,
            "orgName": document.orgName,
            "school": document.school

        }


        algoliaRecords.push(record)

})

collectionIndex.saveObjects(algoliaRecords, (_error: any, content: 
any) => {
    res.status(200).send("COLLECTION was indexed to Algolia 
successfully.");
})

})
```

I keep getting the compile error that says "Variable 'algoliaRecords' implicitly has type 'any[]' in some locations where its type cannot be determined" and I do not know how to fix it. I'm relatively new to algolia but have been doing cloud functions for a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `algoriaRecords` does not have an explicit type. Typically, TypeScript will infer types based on what you end up assigning later on. However, each subsequent `algoriaRecords.push()` operation evolves the type of the variable in accordance with the elements added to it.

A quick fix to this is by explicitly giving a type to algoriaRecords like such:

`const algoriaRecords:Object[] = []`

Furthermore, you can make TypeScript tolerate params with no types declared, see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) for more information by configuring your tsconfig.js file and settting the noImplicitAny to false while removing the strict rule

```
// "strict": true
"noImplicitAny" : false
```